# OpenCV in python. Getting webcam stream works, but error message is printed

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I am writing something in which I need the webcam stream and do some face detection on it. Everything works fine, but I get an error message printed in the terminal, despite of me using  `cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)` which detects any camera connected to my machine.
 I also tried using `cv2` instead of `cv`, and I get the same error:

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
```

Note that the only code I am running currently is `cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)`.Oh and I am using python 2.7.

```
 import cv
 cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)
```

Can someone tell me how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: For `cv2` you should be using `capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` (i.e., 0 and not -1). Also, if everything is working fine than that is ok. These messages are likely coming from `v4l`, maybe it is trying to do something unsupported with your camera.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Just tried your code and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error messages. In my case however they are not fatal, just an indication that python is using v4l2 to probe parameters that happen to be invalid for my camera / os combination.

In my case

```
>>> cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
...
```

But

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

gives ret=true and a numpy image-array for frame.

In my case the video camera is a Logitech, Inc. HD Webcam C910. And I am running Angstrom on a beagleboneblack.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
    import cv
    cv.NamedWindow("Capture", 1)
    cap_1 = cv.CaptureFromCAM(-1)
    While True:
     Frame = cv.QueryFrame(cap_1)
     cv.ShowImage("Capture", Frame)
     cv.WaitKey(1)
```

also, using cv2 and VideoCapture:

```
from cv2 import *
cam = VideoCapture(0)   
s, img = cam.read()
```

EDIT: I found the following information while googling about this error:
The messages: ‘VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument’ come from opencv cap_libv4l.cpp
file.
The ‘querymenu.id” value still has the “V4L2_CTRL_FLAG_NEXT_CTRL” set when enumerating
the menu items.
Following patch solves this:

```
— OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/highgui/src/cap_libv4l.cpp   2011-09-12 20:41:29.000000000 +0200
+++ opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_libv4l.cpp   2011-12-01 19:00:37.503761631 +0100
@@ -489,7 +489,7 @@
{
// printf (” Menu items:\n”);
CLEAR (capture->querymenu);
- capture->querymenu.id = capture->queryctrl.id;
+ capture->querymenu.id = capture->queryctrl.id & ~V4L2_CTRL_FLAG_NEXT_CTRL;
for (capture->querymenu.index = capture->queryctrl.minimum;
(int)capture->querymenu.index queryctrl.maximum;
capture->querymenu.index++)
```

Comment: Same error. Besides, I do not want to show the webcam all the time. I want to detect if someone is sitting in front of a computer, but the user can choose if they want to see the webcam or not.

Comment: did you try VideoCapture(0) ??

Comment: This is irrelevant to how you start the capture. It is an issue regarding how OpenCV uses `v4l` internally, supposing @elaRosca's platform uses `v4l`.

Comment: yes. you are correct. i think he should install the v41 drivers again.

Comment: You can reinstall it (`V 4 L`, not `V 4 1`) 50 times, if opencv is not using it correctly, there is no point in doing so. If some change in `v4l` made the warnings go away, then an updated version might solve it.

Comment: Just for the record, I am a girl. Thanks a lot @mmgp . I will just hide this from the user.

Comment: found some information about the error somewhere. added it in the post.

Comment: I'm not seeing how that patch is correct. The flag `V4L2_CTRL_FLAG_NEXT_CTRL` is set so the call to `v4l2_queryctrl` returns the next control. In addition, before returning the next control, the /flag is cleared/. But, if the driver does not support the flag, EINVAL is returned -- this is very likely to be the case, as per an earlier comment: "it is trying to do something unsupported with your camera". So a correct patch should check whether the camera's driver support the flag or not, and then set the flag or not accordingly.

Comment: Uhm, now seeing OpenCV's code I see the flag is being ORed again too early. This should be reported to the bug tracker. But please, do not apply this patch anywhere, it shouldn't clear that flag because it will stop querying for controls.